# How to add font to windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fonts, windows-phone-7.1

I downloaded and installed [Neverwinter](http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-Neverwinter) font but I can't find it in the FontFamily. How I can add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the technique described [here](http://www.markermetro.com/2011/06/technical/windows-phone-7-custom-fonts/) works for you?

Comment: When I writing `FontFamily` there is not such option

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? Please update your question if you're facing any problems using the provided solution.

Comment: It just didn't have option `FontFamily` so I though it will give me error but it accepted it... So by making everything exactly like the author it still not worked (but I didn't have error, its just not do anything)

Comment: Have a look at the output window and do some research on your own. Can't do any more for you.

Comment: <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomBold}" Text="Custom Bold Oh My!" />

make sure you are using the FONT FAMILY inside a control,